Issue with Setting Visibility of OriginPro Instance in Python Script using originpro Library
I'm trying to use the originpro library to automate graph creation in OriginPro from an external Python script. However, I'm encountering an error when attempting to set the visibility of the OriginPro instance. Below is the script I'm using:
import os
import originpro as op
import sys

# Function to ensure Origin gets shut down if an uncaught exception occurs
def origin_shutdown_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    '''Ensures Origin gets shut down if an uncaught exception'''
    op.exit()
    sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)

if op and op.oext:
    sys.excepthook = origin_shutdown_exception_hook

# Initialize Origin and set visibility
try:
    if op.oext:
        op.set_show(True)
        print("Origin is set to be visible.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error setting Origin visibility: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Check if Origin was initialized correctly
try:
    op.new_sheet()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to start Origin: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    # Load data from file
    wks = op.new_sheet()
    wks.from_file(os.path.join(op.path('e'), 'Samples', 'Graphing', 'Group.dat'))

    # Create a new graph from the 'scatter' template
    graph = op.new_graph(template='scatter')
    gl = graph[0]

    # Add an XY plot from the entire sheet
    plot = gl.add_plot(f'{wks.lt_range()}!(?,1:end)')

    # Group the plots and set group settings
    gl.group()
    plot.colormap = 'Candy'
    plot.shapelist = [3, 2, 1]
    gl.rescale()

    # Save the project
    op.save(os.path.join(op.path('u'), 'Graphing_Project.opju'))

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred during processing: {e}")

# Close the Origin instance
if op.oext:
    op.exit()
    print("Origin has been closed.")


However, I keep encountering the following error when trying to set the visibility with op.set_show(True):
RuntimeError: Exception in OriginExt::ApplicationBase::LT_set_var ==> Invalid pointer

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ... in <module>
    op.set_show(True)

  File ... in set_show
    set_lt_var("@VIS", val)

  File ... in set_lt_var
    po.LT_set_var(name, value)

  File ... in LT_set_var
    return _OriginExt.ApplicationBase_LT_set_var(self, lpcszVar, dValue)

SystemError: <built-in function ApplicationBase_LT_set_var> returned a result with an exception set



Python Version: 3.11
OriginPro Version: 2024
originpro Library Version: Latest
Operating System: Windows 10
I've tried:
Verified that OriginPro is installed and activated correctly.
Ensured that the originpro library is up to date.
Simplified the script to isolate the issue.
Despite these steps, the error persists. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
